# Cloudera's Flume vs Facebook's Scribe

Tags: logging, flume, scribe-server

Is there anyone who got a chance to work on both? I need to set up a framework to move data around. Basically, we have clickstream data coming in as text files. This data needs to be moved around form the app-servers to HDFS, and then to S3 after archival.

I need help in choosing between Flume and Scribe. Which one is better in terms of manageability, setting up and which is easier to customize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the answer posted [here](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-differences-between-Flume-and-Scribe/answer/Jack-Stahl)

I'll quote the answer:

> 1. Flume allows you to configure your Flume installation from a
>      central  point, without having to ssh into every machine, update a
>      configuration  variable and restart a daemon or two. You can start,
>      stop, create, delete  and reconfigure logical nodes on any machine
>      running Flume from any command  line in your network with the Flume
>      jar available.
> 2. Flume also has centralised liveness monitoring. We've heard a
>      couple of  stories of Scribe processes silently failing, but lying
>      undiscovered for  days until the rest of the Scribe installation
>      starts creaking under the  increased load. Flume allows you to see the
>      health of all your logical nodes  in one place (note that this is
>      different from machine liveness monitoring;  often the machine stays
>      up while the process might fail).
> 3. Flume supports three distinct types of reliability guarantees,
>      allowing  you to make tradeoffs between resource usage and
>      reliability. In particular,  Flume supports fully ACKed reliability,
>      with the guarantee that all events  will eventually make their way
>      through the event flow.
> 4. Flume's also really extensible - it's really easy to write your own
>      source or sink and integrate most any system with Flume. If rolling
>      your own  is impractical, it's often very straightforward to have your
>      applications  output events in a form that Flume can understand (Flume
>      can run Unix  processes, for example, so if you can use shell script
>      to get at your data,  you're golden).
>
> This isn't an exhaustive list of benefits to using Flume - I haven't
>   touched  on using decorators for lightweight transformation or
>   metadata extraction,  the configuration language, the ability to run
>   several logical nodes in a  single Flume process, automatic bucketing
>   and rolling of log files in  HDFS... there's lots more about Flume
>   that we're looking forward to sharing  with everyone.
>
> The key difference to me is that Cloudera is actively supporting
>   Flume. While I do generally trust Facebook to maintain great open
>   source projects, Cloudera's business is built around providing support
>   for tools like this, so I have faith that Flume will longterm be
>   better supported. I want to minimize the time I have to think about
>   this particular problem. That said, so far I've had a lot of annoying
>   issues where Flume was either a bit convoluted in its abstraction or
>   buggy in its implementation, as you might expect from a pre-1.0
>   technology. If Asana weren't still in beta, I'd probably have chosen
>   Scribe